# post html associative array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form with array of input elements as shown below.

```
<form method="post" action="sample.php">
<input type="text" name="field[txt][name]" />
<input type="text" name="field[txt][sex]" />
<input type="text" name="field[txt][location]" />
<br /><br />
<input type="text" name="field[num][age]" />
<input type="text" name="field[date][pod]" />
<input type="text" name="field[date][doj]" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

php - print_r($_POST['field']) gives me an output similar to the following when i submit the form as usual.
How can I use jquery-post method to submit 'field[ ][ ]' element to get the same result?

```
Array(
    [txt] => Array
        (
            [name] => sam
            [sex] => male
            [location] => somewhere
        )
    [num] => Array
        (
            [age] => 20
        )
    [date] => Array
        (
            [pob] => 2001-01-01
            [doj] => 2001-01-01
        )
)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular javascript object as a `data` parameter, and jQuery will take care to serialize it as an url parameter :

```
var data = {
    fields: {
        txt: {
            name: "sam",
            sex: "male",
            location: "somewhere"
        },
        num: {
            age: 20
        },
        date: {
             pob: "2001-01-01",
             doj: "2001-01-01"
        }
    }
};
$.post(url, data, function(answer){ ... });
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for all the suggestions provided. So I made few changes and got what i wanted. I add class attribute to input elements as "mc". So I can use `data={mc: $('.mc').serialize()}` and on php side `parse_str($_POST['data']['mc']);print_r($field);`

Comment: Can this be further improved or can there be any serious errors? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @user2987833: if you just want to serialize the full form and send it, go with @Ramesh' answer. you won't need to use `parse_str` on PHP side.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var postData = $("#formId").serializeArray();
$.post(url, postData, function(response){ //do something });
```

Answer (score 0):

try jquery [.Serializre()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
var values = $("form").first().serialize();
```

This code will get all values and serialize to Url Data like it:
"&field[txt][name]=foo1&field[txt][sex]=male"

then you use the Ajax:

```
$.ajax({url: $("form").first().attr("action"), data: values })
```